# How to compute unmixed second partial derivatives in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am currently using tensorflow v1.15 and have some problems with computing unmixed second derivatives. I have never seen a solution on stackoverflow which avoids unnecessary calculations of mixed derivatives. Say my inputs are of size `input = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(type=tf.float32, shape=(None, A, B))` and a scalar `output` (through a series of `tf.matmul` and `tf.reduce_sum`) of shape `(None,)`. I have tried the following in attempt to get the unmixed second derivatives:

- Running `tf.gradients(output, input)` returns the gradient vector `grad1` of shape `(None, A, B)`, the same shape as `input`. Running `grad2 = tf.gradients(grad1, input)` does not give the unmixed second derivatives (even not the Hessian) as Tensorflow seems to have this weird behaviour where you will get `grad2` having the same shape as `input` and `i`-th entry of `grad2` (imagine a single batch) is `sum(d2y/dx[j]dx[i])` for all (dy/dx)s in `grad1`.
- Using `tf.hessians` (or at least some of the code implementation here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.1.0/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py#L333) and extract the unmixed partial derivatives. However, this involves unnecessary computation of mixed second partial derivatives, and it also does it across batches. Hence, the number of computation is `O(batch_size^2 * n_variables^2)`. What I really need is just computations of `O(batch_size*n_variables)`. As expected, I encountered GPU memory issues using this method as the number of variables for my network is pretty large.
- Create a list of inputs of size 1, then reshape it i.e. `input_list=[tf.compat.v1.placeholder(type=tf.float32, shape=1) for _ in range(batch_size*A*B)]`, `input=tf.reshape(input_list, shape=(-1, A, B))`. Again, use a for loop to obtain the first gradient and second gradients via `grad1 = [tf.gradients(output, x) for x in input_list]`, `grad2 = [tf.gradient(g, x) for (g,x) in zip(grad1, input_list)]`. This gives me the desired results and does not compute other mixed partial derivatives. However, it is super slow most likely due to using for loops.

Anyone has any idea how to achieve this?